# need one methods to quantities replace for NSMutableAttributedString same as stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString for NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

Is there a replace method for `NSMutableAttributedString` similar to `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:`  for  `NSString`?

```
NSString *newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

I need the same method for `NSMutableAttributedString`. (I need replace string with image).

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];     
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];

NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment]; 

[mutableAttString replaceCharactersInRange:getanswer     
                      withAttributedString:attachmentString];
```

this way  only replace one time.  i  need quantities  replace

Answer (score 0):

`replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:` is the correct method to use, you just need to find the range that you want to replace first.

To do that, use the `string` method of the attributed string and then one of the `rangeOf...` methods to find the appropriate range you want to replace.

Also, your example shows you just calling `[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init]` and then `replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:`, but you should obviously have something in the mutable string before you try to replace it.